# Linq Order and Group 2 Items in a List by Name

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, visual-studio-2012

I have the following input:

```
 Public Function GetProgramTitles() As List(Of ProgramTitle)
    Dim x As New List(Of ProgramTitle)

    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Outlook.exe", "email1"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Outlook.exe", "email2"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Outlook.exe", "email1"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Outlook.exe", "email2"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Outlook.exe", "email1"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Word.exe", "Doc1"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Outlook.exe", "email2"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Word.exe", "Doc2"))
    x.Add(New ProgramTitle("Outlook.exe", "email1"))

    Return x
End Function
```

I would like to take in this data and return something like this:

Outlook.exe - 7 (instances of program)
-email1 - 4
-email2 - 3
Word.exe - 2
-Doc1 - 1
-Doc2 - 1

This is what I have so far:

```
    Dim data = GetProgramTitles()

    Dim programs = From c In data Select New With {c.Program, c.Title,
        .Programs =
        From o In c.Program
        Group o By c.Program Into Group
        Select New With {.Title = c.Title,
                            .TitleGroup =
                            From o In Group
                            Group o By c.Title Into TitleGroup = Group
                            Select New With {.Program = Program, .Title = TitleGroup}}}

    For Each p In programs
        Console.WriteLine("Program: " & p.Program & " - " & p.Title & " - " & p.Program.Count)
    Next
```

The return I'm getting is not sorted at all and I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Pretty big nested LINQ, indeed. Perhaps you should clarify a bit what this code is expected to do and also the sample outputs you posted (are not immediately related to the inputs). Also I don't see any OrderBy in your code (the records have to be ordered, aren't they?), and you are an expert with this ;)

Comment: Have you tried using [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737912)?

Comment: Lol :)  Yeah I was following a MS example and they did it with this structure for nested items without using OrderBy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to use `Group By` in inner query, not right within the main one.

```
Dim programs =
    From d In data
    Group d By dk = d.Program Into dg = Group, dc = Count()
    Order By dc Descending
    Select New With {
        .Program = dk,
        .Count = dc,
        .Titles =
            From t In dg
            Group t By tk = t.Title Into tg = Group, tc = Count()
            Select New With {
                .Title = tk,
                .Count = tc
            }
    }
```

I changed the returned anonymous type structure a little bit, so you have to change your `For Each` loop as well,

```
For Each p In programs
    Console.WriteLine("Program: {0} - {1}", p.Program, p.Count)
    For Each t In p.Titles
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} - {1}", t.Title, t.Count)
    Next
Next
```

prints

```
Program: Outlook.exe - 7
Title: email1 - 4
Title: email2 - 3
Program: Word.exe - 2
Title: Doc1 - 1
Title: Doc2 - 1
```